# Should I have duplicate class properties or create an extra database table?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to come up with a data model to represent a simple money transaction system.

I have one class to represent a Transaction, and another class to represent a TransactionRecurrence.

Both classes will need properties for an Id, Amount, Type (Withdrawal/Deposit), and a Note of some sort. The Transaction will also hold a TransactionDate, while the TransactionRecurrence will hold some sort of data to represent the recurrence (10th of every month etc.).

My question is: For the properties that both classes will share **should I just duplicate the properties in both classes (which would go against DRY principle), or should I create a new class, say, TransactionInfo that holds the four properties then add a property with that type to the two other classes (which would require a new DB table and foreign key references/SQL joins that would slow down the queries)?**

Edit: For example users will each have a collection of Transactions (which are one-time transactions) and a separate collection of TransactionRecurrences both which they create on the client via a web api. These are stored in the database in separate tables. Then the user can request the transactions through the api. The Transactions can just be added to a collection directly, but the TransactionRecurrences will need to be used to generate more Transaction objects based upon a date range passed in with the request before being added to the collection. The collection is then serialized and sent to the requester.

Comment: I don´t know specifically your case but you could make use of inheritance or abstract classes.

Comment: Do you really need to consider them different classes?  You could just consider a single Transaction as a TransactionRecurrence with a frequency of zero (or something along those lines).

Comment: @Jerrad I thought of doing that as well, but a TransactionRecurrence really isn't something that can exist in real life since it could potentially represent an infinite number of transactions. So I need a class that can actually represent a serializeable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a abstract base class or interface holding those common properties and have your concrete classes implement or inherit that interface or base class. That way you are not duplicating the properties anymore.

Moreover, explain what you are trying to achieve actually and provide better example. So that someone may come up with a better approach.

If every transaction should have recurring facility then you can consider using `Composition` like below

```
public class TransactionRecurrence 
{
  public int DurationPerMonth { get; set; }
}
public class Transaction
{
  public TransactionRecurrence _transref;
  public Transaction(TransactionRecurrence transref)
{
  _transref = transref;
}
//other properties
}
```